# More space between the lines in cases

Tags: math-mode, line-spacing, cases

I'm using the `cases` environment in one of my formulas. Each case is a fraction so I'm using `\displaystyle` to let them appear bigger. However, the result looks quite ugly because there is no space between the lines. The denominator of some fractions overlap with the numerator of the fraction below. Is there a way to increase the spacing? I tried to add empty lines in between but that's obviously too much.

Comment: `\usepackage{mathtools}` and `dcases` instead of `cases`; no `\displaystyle` needed.